# Marriage record for J Heinrich Salsow

Tags: germany, birth-records

I am looking for the marriage record of J Heinrich Salsow and Maria Sophia Dorathea Schröder, she was known as Sophia Shrader in the USA. J Heinrich's birth record is in Volkenshagen parish. Sophia's birth record is in Blankenhagen parish. The family moved, Sophia's youngest brother's birth record is in Volkenshagen parish.

The marriage record would most likely be in Volkenshagen parish, but I can't find it.

```
Passenger List:
Ship: Bark Elbe
Hamburg, Germany to New York, New York
 1 October, 1860

 Joh Salsow       35  m  farmer  Germany  US [J Heinrich]
 Marie Salsow     29  f          Germany  US [née Schröder]
 Doretha Salsow    6m f          Germany  US
```

[image]

The marriage of J Heinrick Salsow to Maria Sophia Dorathea Schröder would have been sometime before the birth of Dorethea in 1860.

I have looked in the following parishes on Archion.de: Blankenhagen, Blankenhagen Dänschenburg, Kessin, Volkenshagen, Cammin b. Laage, Bentwisch, Laage, Sanitz, Kavelstorf, Rövershagen. No luck.

I believe that the following is a false lead, this is probably a different person.
According to another person's tree on Ancestry, this is J Heinrich Salsow's father's birth:
Wilheim Joackim Hinrich Peter Salsow
BIRTH 06 JAN 1798 • Hohen Schwarfs bei Dummerstorf; LK Rostock; M-V

Dummerstorf isn't close to Rostock, so this doesn't make sense to me. Maybe it will make sense to someone else.

Dummerstorf is in Kavelstorf parish, but I don't see this record, although the older records are very hard for me to read, I may have missed it.

The map has yellow pins where I have found ancestors and relatives.

[image]

---

I found the birth of daughter Dorethea. I should have looked for her first. But, I can't find her parents birth in the same parish.

[image]

I found J Heinrich's birth.

[image]

Comment: according to https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hohen_Schwarfs, _Hohen Schwarfs liegt ...rund sieben Kilometer südsüdwestlich von Rostock_ - about 7km from Rostock isn't close?

Comment: There are usually godparents listed in these records. Have you looked at all places they are from (or listed at, rather)? If the parents moved, there might still be family/friends/associates in other communities.

Comment: @jadepx - Since I posted, I noticed that daughter Dorothea has the same surname as her mother. I assume this means that they were not married? In the USA, the stigma (at this time) of not being married when a child was born was worse than not being married when the child was conceived. So, a couple would usually quickly marry if they found out that the woman was pregnant. Do you have any insight into the culture back then?

Comment: The entry actually says that she is illegitimate ("unehelich", below Schröder in the daughter's column). The father's entry says "geständlich", which I would argue means "presumably" in this context (it does not say who informed about the father). I'm not familiar with that region, and whether or not the couple had pressure to marry depends a lot on region and economic situation.

Comment: The [tree at FamilySearch](https://www.familysearch.org/tree/person/details/L26W-GCX) states that the parents marry in 1870 in Illinois, but does not give sources. I had a quick look in Blankenhagen and Volkenshagen, and did not see a matching marriage in 1860 (the window is rather narrow).

Comment: @jadepx - if you answer and say that they probably married in the USA, I will accept it. Then this question can be closed. Two of the Schröder siblings also delayed marrying until after immigration so maybe they had issues with the church. Illinois seems to have less records online than some of the other states, maybe it will show up online someday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a [FamilySearch tree of Henry Salsow](https://www.familysearch.org/tree/person/details/LHN6-WQV), they married in 1870 in Illinois. No sources are given for this.

I looked at 1860 marriages in Blankenhagen and Volkenshagen (Kirchenkreis Mecklenburg) at Archion (Blankenhagen, Trauungen 1837-1875, and Volkenshagen, Trauungen 1837-1875), without finding a matching entry.